# Projects Animation like Google Open Source Projects

Tags: javascript, user-interface, animation, visualization

I want to create an animation just like Google Open Source Projects page to my projects profile.

Check it out here: https://opensource.google.com/projects/explore/featured

I want to have some understanding as to how I can make something like this.

Can someone please help me with any library that could be available for such chart/animation or if not available, can someone help me understand how I can make something like this on my own?

PS: I do know Angular1 well, so if possible, Angular1 code hints would be really appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly. But I can pick up. I would like to learn if you guide me to right direction. I know to use HTML, CSS, JS, Bootstrap and Angular1 in front end technologies.